# Alter Magento Index Fulltext Search?

Tags: php, xml, magento, indexing, full-text-search

I have a unique task that I have been given, and I am in the last leg of it, but this sub-task is proving to be extremely difficult! So you have background: We run a Magento site, and use a custom built SOLR search page.  I am using phpSolrClient to parse the Solr XML and return usable result which I then build the search results page from.

The task I have been given is to have an "attribute" in the back end of Magento, lets call that "search_tags".  The goal is to be able to insert a tag, and it's weight delimitered by commas:

ie `sight^2,hearing^1,smell^3`

I would like to edit the code in Magento's fulltext reindex to break apart the string, and insert that tag X of times into the `fulltext1_en` field.  So it would add "sight" twice, "hearing" once, and "smell" three times.  This is going to allow us to say, put a blender on the page when someone searches for juicers, even though the term "juicer" or "juice" does not appear in the fulltext1_en string.  I have developed the code to pull, split and iterate ...  However I am at an stand-still since I don't know what code to edit to include this in my fulltext1_en during the reindex process.  If anyone has any experience with editing Magento's Fulltext Reindex, your input would be greatly appreciated!  I looked in Indexer.php, but everything in that file is ambiguous at best, so that was no help!  Gotta love Magento!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK for those looking to alter and give "weighted tags" to custom search in Magento using SOLR, I was up all night getting this right, but it works...

First, create a filter in Magento and apply it to all products.  I named mine "search_tags".

Next, use the following formula in that filter for a test item:

```
dude^25,crazyman^25,wierdsearch^25
```

Each word followed by a carat, and then the weight you want to give it.  (This is how many times the word will be repeated and then added to fulltext1_en.)

After that is done, open the following file:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php
```

I know it says MySQL4, pay no attention, SOLR uses this index.

About line 500, you will see the following block:

```
    if ($selects) {
        $select = '('.join(')UNION(', $selects).')';
        $query = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query($select);
        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
```

JUST BELOW this block insert the following:
NOTE:  Do not use the attribute ID I have listed here, that is unique to my setup.  You are going to have to search your database to find this ID.  I used JOIN to join `eav_attributes` with `catalog_product_entity_varchar` and used SELECT to find `attribut_id` and `value` WHERE entity_id = (Insert your product ID here).  It's a pain, but it's the only way. This will return all the attributes for that product. Look for the one that has the tags we entered in earlier, and get it's ID.  Insert that into the code below.

```
      $attr_val = $row['value'];  // Set attr_val so that it can be manipulated in following IF

      if ($row['attribute_id'] == 457) {    // 457 is the ID of MY search_tags filter, yours WILL be different!  It can be found by joining eav_attributes table and catalog_product_entity_varchar and searching for the attribute value and ID where entity_id is X
            $input = $row['value'];             // Set $input to value of filter
            $attr_val = "";                         // Create Emtpy string
            $pieces = explode( ',', $input ); // Explode filter by comma

                foreach ($pieces as $val){
                $i=1;
                $val = explode( '^', $val);    // Explode each "tag" by carat
                    while ($i <= $val[1]) {     // Loop while $i is less than or equal to the number on the right side of the carat
                    $i++;
                    $attr_val = $attr_val . " " . $val[0];  // Append $attr_val with the word to the right side of the carat
                    }                   
                }                       
         }

    $result[$row['entity_id']][$row['attribute_id']] = $attr_val;  //  Modified from Original
```

After you insert that ... Then comment out the following block.

```
$result[$row['entity_id']][$row['attribute_id']] = $row['value']; // ORIGINAL BLOCK  --  UNCOMMENT -- DO NOT DELETE
```

Now run a fulltext reindex, and your fulltext1_en should show that you've added "dude", "crazyman", and "weirdsearch" all 25 times!  When the index is completed, search for any of the tags in your site search: That item you added the tags to should show up close to, if not the top.  Enjoy!